# How to query specific documents in MongoDB using MongoEngine in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a MongoDB Collection which has many documents. Each document looks like this:

```json
{
    "t_id" : "fa2b30c8c39c11eba1208d11d1604e94",
    "e_id" : "fa2b30c8c39c11eba1208d11d1604h51",
    "meta_info" : {
        "pid" : "5f175a0feaace0426851810f",
        "dt_id" : "32574174-c721-46b3-9de4-a5016d595eb4",
        "dt_n" : "qwerty",
        "dt_v" : "3",
        "md_v" : "1"
    },
    "register_time" : ISODate("2021-06-08T19:35:33.515Z")
}
```

Here is the objective I am trying to achieve: I will get value of `t_id, pid, dt_id, dt_n, dt_v, md_v as input`. Now I have to query the collection, such that I fetch document from this collection which matches these values and the one with latest register_time **if there are multiple such documents which match all these values**.

NOTE: pid, dt_id, dt_n, dt_v, md_v <- these values are present inside a sub-json of "meta_info" in each document.
And, my org uses MongoEngine library in Python for MongoDB operations. So I am trying to find a solution using this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching sub-documents ("embedded documents") can be done, and if you have a timestamp, you can easily get the latest one by ordering the query and taking 1 element.

The following simplified case should help you move forward

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

connect()

class MetaInfo(EmbeddedDocument):
    pid = StringField()


class MyDoc(Document):
    meta_info = EmbeddedDocumentField(MetaInfo)
    register_time = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)


MyDoc(meta_info=MetaInfo(pid="001")).save()
MyDoc(meta_info=MetaInfo(pid="002")).save()   # just to add a non-matching one
MyDoc(meta_info=MetaInfo(pid="001")).save()

# matches the 2 doc with pid=001
MyDoc.objects(meta_info__pid="001")     

# matches the latest one that was saved with pid=001
MyDoc.objects(meta_info__pid="001").order_by("-register_time").first()
```